# How can I post method in axios?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, post, axios

So I have such a question, I have a data as I have shared below. Users exist, and each user has their own todo list. How should I write the post method in axios so that when a user with id 1 adds a todo, it falls into its own array. Let each user prepare a todo list for himself. Of course, after registration and login. I can solve it just as an idea. I just don't know how to dump the data into the array inside the selectable object.
For example --

```js
      {
                "users": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee38b041385d900004e78de",
                        "name": "Anar",
                        todos: []
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee38b0e1385d900004e78df",
                       "name": "Mike",
                        todos: []
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee38b1b1385d900004e78e0",
                        "name": "Jane",
                        todos: []
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Let me explain, for example, Jane logs in, then creates a todo for herself and posts it with axios, and this todo should fall into her array.

```js
{
                "users": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee38b041385d900004e78de",
                        "name": "Anar",
                        todos: []
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee38b0e1385d900004e78df",
                       "name": "Mike",
                        todos: []
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee38b1b1385d900004e78e0",
                        "name": "Jane",
                        todos: [
                        {
                           "_id": "xcv12441385d900004e78df",
                          "todo": "todo one",
                        }
                        ]
                    }
              ]
  },
```